# Highlight specific line in markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I'm pretty new in markdown, and I wonder if it's possible to highlight a specific line of a block of source code, like explained in this page

http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Edit :
To be clearer, with the wordpress plugin, you can write something like this :

```
[code highlight="2,3"]
This line won't be highlighted.
This line will be highlighted.
This line will be highlighted.
This line won't be highlighted.
[/code]
```

But obviously, this isn't a markdown syntax.

Comment: If that article explains it, then why do you ask about it here? With other words: Can you show what you've tried, and what you're having problems with?

Comment: This article is about a plugin for wordpress, which can highlight specific lines of codes.

I just want to know if we can do the same thing with the markdown syntax

Comment: According to [this article](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) markdown inside markdown is not processed inside a code block, so I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Github could you please add this functionnality :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On SO, langauge highlighting is possible as explained in [Advanced Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) but not formatting within code blocks.

```
This is a code block
Markdown is **not** processed
```

You might mimic what you want by using quote:

> This line won't be highlighted.
>   **This line will be highlighted.**
>   **This line will be highlighted.**
>   This line won't be highlighted.

You might also mimic what you want by using two spaces at end of each line:

This line won't be highlighted.
**This line will be highlighted.**
This line won't be highlighted.

But of course, these are not then rendered in monospaced font nor do you get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yeah but I don't want language highlighting, I just want to highlight a specific line.

Comment: Can't be done in [standard Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax/txt) or in [GFM](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) as far as I know

Answer (score 7):

It can be done, but there is no Markdown syntax for it, at least not on the most common flavors. Fortunately, also on the most common flavors you can embed **HTML**.

My solution:

### Example

```
function main() {
    __config_bash
    __config_xdg_dirs
}
```

### Code

```html
<pre><code>
    function main() {
        __config_bash
        <strong>__config_xdg_dirs</strong>
    }
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Short, but nice.

Comment: You need to provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be regarding markdown on GitHub as that’s how you tagged it. But it also pops up googling for markdown in general which is why I’m providing another answer:

In some flavours of markdown, highlighting lines can be achieved by using syntax similar to your example for the WordPress plugin:

```
<code text [highlight_lines_extra="2,3"]>Line 1 is not highlighted.
Line 2 is highlighted.
Line 3 is highlighted.</code>
```

This doesn’t work on stackoverflow either. It does on DokuWiki though: https://www.dokuwiki.org/syntax_highlighting